# Parameter expansion not working in "find -exec"

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a **bash script** as above, but the parameter expansion is not working with the `EXC` variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
EXC="--exclude='*.js' --exclude='*.sh'"
find /path -exec grep ${EXC} "xxx" {} \; >> result.txt
```

Options in the `EXC` variable are not used by the `grep` call as it still parse JavaScript files...

Also tried

```
find /path -exec grep $EXC "xxx" {} \; >> result.txt
```

Comment: This is related to [Bash FAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the single quotes are not removed from the parameter expansion, so `grep` is receiving `'*.js'` as the pattern, not `*.js` as you want. You need to use an array to hold the arguments:

```
exc=( "--exclude=*.js" "--exclude=*.sh" )  # No single quotes needed
find /path -exec grep "${exc[@]}" "xxx" {} \; >> result.txt
```

The quoted parameter expansion prevents `*.js` and `*.sh` from being expanded by the shell in the same way that quoting them when used literally does. `--exclude='*.js'` and `'--exclude=*.js'` would both result in the same argument being passed to `grep`, as would the minimalist `--exclude=\*.js`. You could also define your array as

```
exc=( --exclude "*.js" --exclude "*.sh" )
```

since the long option and its argument can be specified as one word containing `=` or as two separate words.

Comment: It's not a single-quote problem. I tried with escaped double quotes and it didn't work neither. The array did the trick, but to me, how shell expansion works is still too unclear. While a simple `var=string` expanded with `${var}` is ineffective, an `var=(strings...)` expanded with `"${var[@]}"` works. I expected the same logic to be applied on variables and arrays but apparently it's not.

Comment: It is different, because arrays were introduced precisely to solve the problem you are having with a regular variable. When you type `grep --exclude='*.js'` literally, the shell removes the single quotes because they are only used to tell the shell that `*.js` should not be expanded. `grep` receives the literal string `--exclude=*.js` as the argument. When you store that string in a variable, though, the single quotes have no special meaning. The string `--exclude='*.js'` is treated as a pattern that almost certainly fails to match, and so is passed literally to `grep` *along with* the quotes.

Comment: Now I get it... but why `var="--exclude=*.js"` still doesn't work with `cmd "${var}"`? No single-quote here so nothing the shell should worry about as my variable is just a casual string.

Comment: That should work. Note that there is little difference between single and double quotes; single quotes simply suppress parameter expansion.

Comment: My bad, you were right the whole run. Removing single-quotes in the string variable was the solution to my initial problem! As you said, expansion works, but options passed to the command line after this expansion was giving quoted options to grep, which was not "matching"

Answer (score 1):

You can filter `find` results with `!` (not) operator combined with `-name` option. To exclude `.js` and `.sh` files:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.js' ! -name '*.sh' -exec grep xxx  {} \;
```

Comment: My problem is not to exclude some files, I can write the entire command line for that. The problem is that i'm using a variable to hold some arguments, and parameter expansion does not replace the ${} thing by its value in the command line... I tried your solution fit with my requirements and it still doesn't work as grep keeps parsing .js files

Answer (score 0):

It still parses or it's only applied by find also on files that you are trying to exclude?

Anyway, why not use only *grep -r* instead of *find* plus *grep*?

```
grep -r --exclude='*.js' --exclude='*.sh' "xxx" /path
```

Comment: Filtering is ineffective in both find or grep flavour using a variable and parameter expansion. I'm not using a recursive grep because it parses binary files, which is not relevant in my case.

Comment: Again, my problem is not to filter files. The problem is that I need to parameterize my command line as I can (in some use cases) have a lot of different file extensions to exclude

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that i'm using a variable to hold some arguments, and parameter expansion does not replace the ${} thing by its value in the command line...

You can launch a subshell wich will perform what you want

```
#!/bin/bash
EXC="--exclude='*.js' --exclude='*.sh'"
find /path -exec bash -c "grep ${EXC} 'xxx' {}" \; >> result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

these could help you;

```
#!/bin/bash
EXC="--exclude='*.js' --exclude='*.sh'"
find  /path -exec echo "grep ${EXC} 'xxx' {}" \; | bash > result.txt
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
EXC="*js,*sh"
find  /path -exec echo "grep --exclude={${EXC}} 'xxx' {}" \; | bash  > result.txt
```